# Mysql like query in inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query but it is returning 0 records. I am not sure why it is returning zero record.

Here is MySql query.

```
SELECT a.skills_name 
FROM skills a inner join job b 
ON a.skills_name like b.keywords 
GROUP BY a.skills_name 
ORDER BY a.skills_name ASC limit 15
```

Data in skills table is like this.

```
skills_id   skills_name
        1   It support
        2   IT technician
        4   sales
```

Data in Job table is like this.

```
sales, marketing
IT Support, IT Head
```

Please advise.

Comment: `on b.keywords like coancat('%', a.skills_name, '%')`

Comment: Can u give an expected output?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel solution worked. Thanks Paul. Please post that in answer.

Comment: How do yoi join Job table and skills  .. is not clear could you show the job schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LIKE` without placeholders ("%") is the same as using `=`. If your pseudocode for the JOIN condition is `b.keywords CONTAINS a.skills_name` then  you need `b.keywords LIKE coancat('%', a.skills_name, '%')`

```
SELECT a.skills_name 
FROM skills a inner join job b 
    ON b.keywords LIKE coancat('%', a.skills_name, '%')
GROUP BY a.skills_name 
ORDER BY a.skills_name ASC limit 15
```

As other already mentioned you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicates instead of `GROUP BY` - (`SELECT DISTINCT a.skills_name`)

You should also consider to use a normalized schema instead of storing multiple values in a string column. In your case the `job` table would look like:

```
id | keyword
----------------
 1 | sales
 1 | marketing
 2 | IT Support
 2 | IT Head
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.skills_name 
FROM skills a inner join job b 
    ON b.keyword = a.skills_name
ORDER BY a.skills_name ASC limit 15
```

Answer (score 1):

If you job table column for join is keywords 
Seems you don't need like and group by  (use distinct if you don't have aggregation function)

```
SELECT distinct a.skills_name 
FROM skills a inner join job b  ON a.skills_name  = b.keywords 
ORDER BY a.skills_name ASC limit 15
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Your `on` clause is wrong. The [like keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) doesn't say "is it similar" but "does it contain X" (and using the `%` allows you to specify that it doesn't matter what comes after and/or before)

In addition, there is no reason for the `group by`. The use of the `group by` is when you want to perform some aggregation functions like `sum`/`count`. I assume you are using it here to get each value once. For that use [`distinct`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Use this:

```
SELECT a.skills_name 
FROM skills a 
join job b 
on lower(b.keywords) like ('%' + lower(a.skills_name) + '%')
ORDER BY a.skills_name
limit 15
```

Comment: Let me try. Voted up.

Comment: still no record return. any advise.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine - The code above was missing the `+` before the secod `%` and thus would not compile. This will work